# AWS CLI describe volume attachment information

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

In AWS CLI I am trying to get the ec2 volume "Attachment Information"

I see how I can find the Instance information, but this does not include the Attachment Information. The information I am looking for can actually be found in the ec2 Volume Management Console, but I want to use CLI to list it as text so I can put it in a text file. Is this possible.

`aws ec2 describe-volumes --output text --region us-east-1` <-- doesn't show the attachment information of the instance description.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-volumes.html

UPDATE: The above command does output the attachment information "i-1234567" but NOT the Instance Description. Example i-1234567 (AWSServer)

Comment: hmmm, it should show attached true/fasle and the phyiscal path if it is attached. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attachment information is included in the `describe-volumes` function.

`aws ec2 describe-volumes --output text --region us-east-1` includes a section called `ATTACHMENTS` (if attached), such as the following:

```
VOLUMES us-east-1a      2016-03-22T23:00:54.577Z        False   300     100    available        vol-12345678    gp2
TAGS    backup  yes
VOLUMES us-east-1d      2015-12-08T21:24:25.007Z        False   24      8      snap-12345678    in-use  vol-12345678    gp2
ATTACHMENTS     2015-12-08T21:24:25.000Z        True    /dev/xvda       i-12345678      attached        vol-12345678
```

The above example shows two volumes, one attached and one not attached.

The `ATTACHMENTS` section includes the date of attachment, the "Delete on Terminate" flag, device name, attached EC2 instance, and status.

**Update:**

In the AWS Console, the "Attachment Information" column displays the EC2 intance ID and the "Name" tag from the EC2 instance. The "Name" tag is not included in the results from `describe-volumes`.

To get the "Name" tag, you'll need to call `aws ec2 describe-instances`. Either a blanket call to get all EC2 instances, or by including the `--instance-id` parameter to get the EC2 instance you care about. The response from `describe-instances` includes the tags.

Comment: Correct and thats what I have. I figured out the disconnect. In the Attachment information we inputted a description. Its that description that is not showing.  So for example i-12345678 (AWSServer). Thats what I want listed. Updating my question. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my answer.